# Recurrence relation and time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

What is the recurrence relation and time complexity for the following pseudo-code?

```
temp = 1 
repeat 
    for i=1 to n 
        temp = temp +1 
    n=n/2
until n>=1
```

Comment: [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823)

Comment: recurrence relation? Where is the recursion here?

Comment: From my knowledge, recurrence relation can be defined on this because it will run the same loop (for loop) again for a value of n that is half each time, so T(n/2) would be a part of the recurrence. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes you can, but it is not really necessary.

Comment: So, what would be the time complexity here? The book I am referring has it solved as T(n) = T(n/2) + n and applying the master's theorem, O(n) is the answer mentioned. But if you consider it, the loop will run n + n/2 + n/4 + n/16 and so on until n becomes 1. Isn't that greater than O(n)?

Comment: Note that the outer loop runs only once if n>=2. Does this help?

Comment: Even if the outer loop were different so that you get `n + n/2 + n/4 + n/16 + ...` this would be at most `2n`, so still `O(n)`.

Comment: Another hint: you could have avoided all the downvotes if you would have put the info from your last comment into the question from the beginning.

Comment: How does the outer loop run only once if n>=2? Say n=4 then outer loop would run 3 times - n=4, n=2, n=1 and finally be terminated when n=0.

Comment: No, the loop stops when n >= 1 at the end of the loop. it runs `until n>=1`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When we are dealing with asymptotic notations like Big-Oh , Omega and Theta, we don't consider the constants. No doubt your time complexity will go like

```
    n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1
```

but if you add on this decreasing G.P series you will get exact answer equals to c*n where c will be some constant greater than 1. But in Asymptotic notations as I said earlier, constants doesn't matter so whether value of c is 2 or 50 or 100 or 10000 or anything, it will be O(n) only.

Another thing, Try not to use Master's Theorem for solving recurrence relations and use Recursive Tree method as it is pure conceptual and will help you in building up your concepts and can be used in every case. Master's theorem is like short cut and also have limitations.

Comment: "No doubt your loop will run like ...": no, it doesn't. See the comments to the question.

Comment: @Henry Actually i wanted to refer about time complexity here. Time complexity will go like n + n/2 + n/4 and so on.... Its like taking n time problem breaks into one sub problem of size n/2 and using this we will get the result as in mentioned in book